# SThreshold MSComm To SerialPort

Tags: c#, vb6

I have a VB6 project that I am trying to convert to c#.
the project uses the property myMSComm.SThreshold = 1 of MSComm, What is the equivalent for serialPort in c#?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no direct equivalent, SerialPort doesn't have a TransmitBufferEmpty event.  It is pretty meaningless kind of event on modern hardware, UARTs have a FIFO that will buffer output and continue transmitting bytes even after the transmit buffer is empty.

You can somewhat emulate it by using the SerialPort.BaseStream.BeginWrite() method.  The callback you specify runs when the write completes.  You can then call BeginWrite() again to write more data.  Not exactly the same as an SThreshold value of 1 since the transmit buffer will be full when BeginWrite completes.  Beware that the callback runs on a threadpool thread so you have to be careful to interlock.

Comment: thank you for your answer. I just want to understand something, if the transmit buffer is empty, what it will send?